# Java Block last JFrame from being focused like a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, joptionpane

I got a program. When I clic on a button, it opens a 2nd JFrame. (NB: I do not not want to use a JOptionPane because it is too basic). I would like, just like the JOptionPane, that my first  Frame cannot be focusable and if clicked, the 2nd one will blink like the JOP.

Basicly: - I want to have the 2nd Jframe to be the focused frame out of the two and the 1st one cannot be clicked until the 2nd is closed.

Comment: You still can use `JOptionPane`. It's very customizable and/or use a modal `JDialog`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to:

- Either use a ***modal*** JDialog in place of the second JFrame
- Or use a *JOptionPane*, which really is a modal JDialog with a little extra window dressing. These guys are more powerful than you realize, and they can hold most any complex GUI, including one filled with tons of components, you give to it.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ComplexOptionPane extends JPanel {
   private PlayerEditorPanel playerEditorPanel = new PlayerEditorPanel();
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(12, 30);

   public ComplexOptionPane() {
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      textArea.setFocusable(false);
      textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 16));
      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Get Player Information") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, playerEditorPanel,
                  "Edit Player JOptionPane", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
               for (PlayerEditorPanel.FieldTitle fieldTitle : PlayerEditorPanel.FieldTitle
                     .values()) {
                  textArea.append(String.format("%10s: %s%n",
                        fieldTitle.getTitle(),
                        playerEditorPanel.getFieldText(fieldTitle)));
               }
            }
         }
      }));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ComplexOptionPane mainPanel = new ComplexOptionPane();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComplexOptionPane");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PlayerEditorPanel extends JPanel {
   enum FieldTitle {
      NAME("Name"), SPEED("Speed"), STRENGTH("Strength"), HEALTH("Health");
      private String title;

      private FieldTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title;
      }

      public String getTitle() {
         return title;
      }
   };

   private static final Insets WEST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
   private static final Insets EAST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0);
   private Map<FieldTitle, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<FieldTitle, JTextField>();

   public PlayerEditorPanel() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Player Editor"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
      GridBagConstraints gbc;
      for (int i = 0; i < FieldTitle.values().length; i++) {
         FieldTitle fieldTitle = FieldTitle.values()[i];
         gbc = createGbc(0, i);
         add(new JLabel(fieldTitle.getTitle() + ":", JLabel.LEFT), gbc);
         gbc = createGbc(1, i);
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
         add(textField, gbc);

         fieldMap.put(fieldTitle, textField);
      }
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;

      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      gbc.insets = (x == 0) ? WEST_INSETS : EAST_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = (x == 0) ? 0.1 : 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      return gbc;
   }

   public String getFieldText(FieldTitle fieldTitle) {
      return fieldMap.get(fieldTitle).getText();
   }

}
```

code borrowed from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860834/522444).