# JOptionPane with arranged multiple inputs

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

I am currently working on a GUI and I want to display a pop up window identical to the one shown below using JOptionPane. I am currently able to display the JTextField and JLabel but not in the same specific location as the one shown in the picture. In addition, I am not able to store the user input into variables. Can someone please provided me with hints or some examples of code so I can continue on the right path?
This is what I am doing:

GridBagConstraints layoutConst = null; // GUI component layout
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

```
    JLabel sNameLabel = null;               // Label for hourly salary
    JLabel sDepLabel = null;                // Label for yearly salary

    JTextField sNameField = null;           // Displays hourly salary 
    JTextField sDepField = null;            // Displays yearly salary

    sNameLabel = new JLabel("Student Name:");
    sDepLabel = new JLabel("Student Department:");

    sNameField = new JTextField(15);
    sNameField.setEditable(true);
    sDepField = new JTextField(15);
    sDepField.setEditable(true);


    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 0;
    layoutConst.gridy = 0;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    myPanel.add(sNameLabel, layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 0;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    myPanel.add(sNameField, layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 0;
    layoutConst.gridy = 0;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    myPanel.add(sDepLabel, layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 1;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    myPanel.add(sDepField, layoutConst);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, myPanel, "Add Course", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

[What I Want pic is in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5mmc.jpg)

Comment: Just put them in a JPanel that uses GridBagLayout.

Comment: One of the awesome features of `JOptionPane`, is if you pass it a `Component` via the `message` parameter, it will simply show that component

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22048779/522444)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) method.

> @param **message** the `Object` to display

The `message` parameter can be a simple string or a complex object like a JPanel.

For the layout of your panel, we can use a layout manager called [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#gridbag).

For more information, check the following guide: [`How To Use GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Here's a quick example of everything together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

    JLabel label;

    label = new JLabel("Student Name");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(label, constraints);

    JTextField studentNameField = new JTextField(20);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(studentNameField, constraints);

    label = new JLabel("Departament");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(label, constraints);

    JTextField departamentField = new JTextField(20);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(departamentField, constraints);

    label = new JLabel("Course");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(label, constraints);

    JTextField courseField = new JTextField(20);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(courseField, constraints);

    Object[] options = {"OK", "CANCEL"};

    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

    if (result == 0) {

        String studentName = studentNameField.getText();

        String departament = departamentField.getText();

        String course = courseField.getText();

        System.out.println(studentName);

        System.out.println(departament);

        System.out.println(course);

    }

}
```